# Display Top 5 Lines From Unix Command Output

Tags: unix, command, pipe, xxd

I am trying to display only the first 5 or so lines of Unix command `xxd file/path.dmg` similarly to the [`head()`](https://www.journaldev.com/43863/head-and-tail-function-r) command in `r`.

As of now, I am simply trying to spam "ctrl + c" to halt execution as fast as possible, but unsurprisingly I'm not fast enough. I'm aware of the term "pipping" and I'd imagine this method could be useful. I might get arthritis if I don't find a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

`xxd file/path.dmg | head -n [# of lines]` will do the trick.

You can additionally use `xxd file/path.dmg | head -n [# of lines] > output.txt` to save the results to a text file! :)